# How to add API Key & Secret authentication to an API developed with AWS API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

I have developed a nice and working PutItem, GetItem, and UpdateItem API for DynamoDB using AWS API Gateway. Now, since anyone can access the API, by just capturing it's invoke URL - that's a problem for me, because my DynamoDB contains some delicate data like name, email, address, etc.

Now, most of the 3rd party common APIs I use, they have both API Key, and API Secret for authentication. Now, what I want to do is :

- For the `PutItem` & `UpdateItem` API, I would send API Key & API Secret in the headers.
- For the `GetItem` API, I would attach them in the URL like - `?apikey=xxxx&secret=xxxx`.

Is this possible to do? How can I authenticate my APIs with Keys & Secret?

Any help is Appreciated :)
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly keep it consistent and in the headers, not the query strings.

Secondly you can indeed do this using a [Lambda Authorizer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-use-lambda-authorizer.html).

By adding a Lambda authorizer you could validate the keys sent against some kind of data store (for example a DynamoDB table).

If they're correct you can return a policy that would allow or deny specific resources or methods.

You can also cache the response based on the headers so that any reattempts within the TTL would automatically have the allow/deny policy instantly respond.

Comment: Thanks, @mokugo! I can't understand what do you mean by '_keep it consistent and in the headers_' - can you please elaborate on this one? Also, what I only want is I would send a specific key and secret key through headers on each & every call, and the API would put/uptdate/get item ONLY if the key & secret match. Else, it would respond with some error. Is this possible to do? Thanks!

Comment: You mentioned for the get request you wanted to use query string parameters. Better to use headers for all as it'll stop duplicate processing needing to be done. Custom authorizers cache the policy :)

Comment: Ok, got it. So, as I mentioned, in my previous comment - '**_what I only want is I would send a specific key and secret key through headers on each & every call, and the API would put/uptdate/get item ONLY if the key & secret match. Else, it would respond with some error._**' : Can you assist on this more? Can this be done Lambda function you suggested? Thanks again! :)

Comment: Yes this can be done via a Lambda function checkout https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-use-lambda-authorizer.html under "EXAMPLE: Create a request-based Lambda authorizer function"